# Why did the developer survey not include all questions?

Tags: support, survey-2020

I just took the 2020 developer survey. As usual, there are many questions regarding my coding skills and my career status. I found it odd that the survey did not ask too many questions around my career, like the compensation I receive for my work.

I originally wanted to ask why this is the case, and to better prove my point, I started the survey again in incognito mode with the intention of checking how many questions around my career are in there in total (but with no intention of submitting)

To my surprise, the survey now included several more questions, mainly in the categories that I missed before. More specifically, during my first round, I was not asked the following questions:

- How satisifed are you with your current job?
- How many people are employed by the company you currently work for?
- Which currency do you use day-to-day?
- What is your current total compensation?
- On average, how many hours per week do you work?
- How often do you work overtime or beyond the formal time expectation of your job?
- Do you think your company has a good onboarding process?
- How could onboarding at your company be improved?
- Does your company have a dedicated DevOps person?
- How important is the practice of DevOps to scaling software development?
- Which of the following best describes your current job-seeking status?
- In general, what drives you to look for a new job? Select all that apply.
- When job searching, how do you learn more about a company?
- Imagine that you are deciding between two job offers with the same compensation, benefits, and location. Of the following factors, which 3 are MOST important to you?

I remember the questions before this block of questions, as well as all the questions which came after. I also remember submitting, and when I try to open the survey again, it tells me that I have already taken it. I also disabled my adblocker as per the recommendations of the survey.

I then wanted to check whether or not the questions above where hidden from me because of earlier answers I gave, so I started the survey once again, this time making sure that I answer in the exact same way as before. But I still saw the questions.

I am familiar with the concept of A/B testing, but I never heard of this in the scope of research and surveys. Since I am out of other explanations, I wanted to ask here:

Why didn't I see the aforementioned blocks of questions when I initially took the survey?

Comment: I think they're randomized but you might have to say that you're working somewhere.